# What is the best way to go about storing application options: file system or db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms

We are looking to find the best way to store user options (skills, degrees, industries, languages, etc.) for drop downs. The options are between a JSON file we can store on the server file system or in the db (MongoDB).

What are the pros and cons of each method and how will they affect server performance under heavy usage?

Comment: File system vs. database [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=file+system+vs.+database&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=file+system+vs.+database&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5223j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).  Lots of articles to read.  The answer is that "it depends" upon a lot of factors that are unique to your particular application.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​If you need to query the data, the answer is always db. If not, just pick one and move on.

Comment: just a quick clarification question.  Are you asking about storing the json file on the client or the server?

Comment: @WindRaven on the server.

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: @KenroyGeorge ok.  I tend to go towards the flat file until i have a good case to implement a db data store for other data.   Once I have the db every thing goes in it including the config values.  Of course I also hide the actual data store behind a repository interface so changing it out later is easier to do as long as the interface does not change.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance. Decided to go the db route since that allows for a bit more flexibility based and future expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this more on-topic, this is a way to go about determining which one is better for a particular situation. Note: you may find that the best solution could change over time as your application's requirements change.

**Do Both:** Sorry, if you want to really find out the best solution, I recomend doing both and comparing your results. This accomplishes a few things:

- Performance comparison (Assuming you can simulate a load)
- Learn how to implement both in case you need to change.
- Design your code so swapping data sources is not that difficult.
- Part of this process could be used to create a unit or integration test.

Again, this is all predicated on not know which one will work for your situation, so you build your app in order to change the data sources as needed. You may find a need for some sort of in-memory data caching for this sort of thing. You'll be ready to do this without a major change to your application.

Comment: Yup, make a generic interface for your options so you can use either a database or a file-system.

Comment: @JeffO Thanks! I will indeed do a combination of both: large menu options will be stored in the db while shorter lists will be stored on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

There are very good arguments for and against each option.  If you were speaking with regards to configuration data I would think a longer and more in-depth discussion would be warranted.

Since you're talking about *application data*, I would be inclined to believe that unless you know for certain that these data would never need to be queryable for reports and/or that it was static data that would never change, this data should belong in the database.

Answer (score 0):

#### Json Way

**Pros:**

- Faster than DB
- There is no weight for server/job

**Cons:**

- Update/Edit content is difficult.

#### DB Way

**Pros:**

- Can be develop for speed

**Cons:**

- Sometimes its unnecessary if it isn't change.
- If its grow, it will weight for server

---

My suggest is using DB. Because you can develop for speed. Generally, I'm using JSON for static weight contents.